# Как поменять curl метод POST на GET?

Tags: php, curl

Такова проблемка, есть сервис вида `site.ua/get_new.php?nomer=998166803`, информацию с которого пытаюсь получить. Если напрямую ввести адрес в браузере, все хорошо, информация выводится. Если парсить curl'ом - парсится `<h3>... не найдена</h3>`

Стандартный набор опций, который работает на других сайтах, часть кода:

```
'curl_options'        => [
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://www.site.ua/get_new.php?',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 20,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0',
    CURLOPT_REFERER        => 'http://www.site.ua/'
]
```

Может проблема в кодировках? Работаю utf8, сайт на cp1251. Пробовал отправлять заголовки из браузера, Accept-Language и другие.

Можно ли получить урл, к которому обращается curl с уже сформированными постданными, чтобы проверить урл? Как порешить проблемку?

Comment: я попробовал браузером и получил "ПОМИЛКА | СТОРІНКА НЕ ЗНАЙДЕНА". это так и должно быть?

Comment: совершенно не очевидно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом разобрался благодаря материалам
- https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/curl-request-in-diff-methods/30571/3
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225409/how-to-switch-from-post-to-get-in-php-curl

Когда используется метод GET надо сразу формировать урл запроса таким образом

```
$qry_str = "?x=10&y=20";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/test.php' . $qry_str);
```

`CURLOPT_HTTPGET` или `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` использовать смысла нет, так как в последних версия `curl` метод `GET` используется по-умолчанию. Поэтому используем банальный `CURLOPT_POST` и формируем строку как в коде выше.

Comment: Я же об этом писал в ответе 20ч назад )))

Comment: @Majestio мне этого не было понятно, что конкретно никаким другим способом не получить по методу GET. Мне же надо много номеров мониторить, мало ли вы посоветовали тупо данный урл парсить, без динамической подстановки других номеров, есть тут и такие советчики.

Comment: Я совсем не такой :) И чего народ ответ минусует, вот жеж ... поправлю немножко)

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли получить урл, к которому обращается curl с уже сформированными постданными, чтобы проверить урл? Как порешить проблемку?

Можно, используя [`curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php), например так:

```
<?php
// создание нового cURL ресурса
$ch = curl_init();

// установка URL и других необходимых параметров
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Выдача URL в браузер
echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

// завершение сеанса и освобождение ресурсов
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: так не подходит, CURLOPT_URL устанавливаю `http://www.sat.ua/new/templates/tracking_get_new.php?` чтобы потом динамически подставлять разные номера постданными CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Comment: Ваш целевой сайт, походу, не умеет работать с POST-запросами. Он работает с GET. Вот и весь вопрос. Введите просто `http://www.sat.ua/new/templates/tracking_get_new.php` получите `"Накладная на груз по идентификатору не найдена"`, а если в URL добавить параметры - то все Ok.

Comment: у меня была эта мысль, но как изменить метод запроса на GET? Пробовал CURLOPT_HTTPGET и CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, никаких изменений.

Comment: В коде, который я привел - как раз GET и используется. Если замените `echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL)` на `$content = curl_exec($ch)`, то в переменной `$content` будет содержимое ответа сервера, ну или `FALSE`, если все плохо.